# Using CNAME records to redirect to HTTPS when HSTS is active

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, cname-record, hsts

We have a website running in HTTPS on the following URL: abc.example.com.

The problem is that our client thought that any website URL should start with `www` and has printed `www.abc.example.com` on all its labels...

No problem, I simply created a redirect rule using IIS's URL Rewrite feature to redirect all hostnames to `https://abc.example.com`. So far so good.

A few months ago, we received an e-mail from their IS department, stating that `abc.example.com` was lacking the `Strict-Transport-Security` header. They asked us to implement the following header:

```
Strict-Transport-Security = max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload.
```

At that time I was not fully aware of the exact function of this header, so I blindly added it to the website. I did test the website, I just never tested it using `www.abc.example.com`.

I only found out just now that this HSTS header will redirect all HTTP URLs to HTTPS URLs by itself, resulting in neglecting my custom redirection rules. The problem now is that users enter `http://www.abc.example.com` and get redirected to `https://www.abc.example.com`, instead of `https://abc.example.com`, resulting in a SSL certificate error because `www.abc.example.com` does not have a SSL certificate.

As long as `includeSubDomains` is active, there is very little I seem to be able to do to prevent this from happening on the webserver, unless I'd set up a SSL certificate specifically for `www.abc.example.com`.

That's why I thought of trying to solving this by redirecting at DNS level, using a CNAME record: `www.abc.example.com. CNAME abc.example.com.`

My question is, will this work? When a user enters `http://www.abc.example.com`, will the CNAME record first redirect this URL to `http://abc.example.com` and then succesfully redirect to `https://abc.example.com` using the HSTS header? Or will the parameter `preload` prevent this from happening, even at DNS level?

Any suggestions or help is appreciated.

Comment: No. DNS has nothing to do with redirects, it only resolves names to IP addresses. Also, with HSTS active, the browser will not even try `http://`. You will have to get the cert for www.abc.domain.com and configure IIS to use it (SSL certs can be very cheap or even free these days...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it will not work. There's no such thing as redirecting on the DNS level; redirection is a feature of HTTP protocol, while DNS (both `A` and `CNAME`) records are used only for resolving the IP address.

There's also no use trying revoke the situation by removing the header,

```
Strict-Transport-Security = max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload.
```

as it will be cached on every browser for `31536000` seconds i.e. 365 days.

However, if you don't implement HSTS this way, you don't gain much of its benefits as someone could try to modify `http://www.abc.example.com` before it gets redirected to `https://`.

Here, the only exit might be getting a wildcard certificate covering `*.abc.example.com`, or a multi-hostname certificate having both as *Subject Alternative Name*s.

Comment: Okay thank you. It's clear for me that the only way to solve this will be to get a valid SSL certificate for www.abc.example.com.